# SqlServer Merge Replica push - exec sys.sp_MSaddmergetriggers throws error

Tags: sql-server, merge, replication, push

i'm stuck trying to solve an issue with a brand-new installation of two sql-server 2017 developer edition,  in two different commodity server.

The problem arise with the tentative of merge-replicate one database.
Every chanche to sync the subscriber ( in a lot of different combo and scenario ) ends up with the following error:

```
exec sys.sp_MSaddmergetriggers N'systemunits', N'dbo', null, 0**************deferred cmd exec completed

Cannot find the object 'MSmerge_ctsv_A6203259D69B49709C5BE266A99D0DBC', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

I have installed the `default-instace` of sql server on both the server, no rename of the server has been done after the installation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Verbose log of the issue give me no hints on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Source:  Merge Replication Provider
Number:  -2147201001
Message: The merge process was unable to deliver the snapshot to the Subscriber. If using Web synchronization, the merge process may have been unable to create or write to the message file. When troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose history logging and specify an output file to which to write.
Source:  Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0
Message: Cannot find the object 'MSmerge_ctsv_A6203259D69B49709C5BE266A99D0DBC', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Answer (score 1):

After a whole day , i finally find a solution to the problem!
It seems that the replica agent use the Domain-name ( not the ip or the port ) of the subscriber to replicate without issue, every mismatch or change in the DNS ( for example... localhost instead of the hostname , the port number that follows the named instance etc ) cause an error in the sync process.

To avoid any issue, i create sql-ALIAS referencing the destination subscribers, and use those alias in the definition of the subscription.

Example: 
to point to the server "10.12.12.5\SqlExpress,49170" i create the alias:
\SqlExpress
port: 49710
protocol: TCP/IP
Server: 10.12.12.5\SqlExpress

and use those alias ( i.e. \SqlExpress ) as the host subscriber.